# Calculate line graph x and y without knowing max/min of data set

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

This question pertains to programing but is really a math question.

I am building an application that draws a line graph, similar to a stock line graph.  The problem is I am not starting with a known set of numbers. The values will come in based on an altitude value. So, when I start the graph I have no idea what the max and min values of my data set will be, because they max might not come along for some time.

[image]

Like I mentioned, these values will be added to the graph when I receive and elevation value but I don't know these until they are received from my device (iPhone).

**Is there a formula used to calculate a line graph for unknown values? How can I know what x and y values to use for each new value received? And how can I calculate the min and max of the graph?**

Comment: The usual approach is to choose some default scale for your graph and rescale if the data goes out of range.  Maybe you start with 0-1mi on x and current altitude (rounded) +-200 ft on y.  Then when somebody goes past 1 mi, change the horizontal (which requires updating all the points) to 0-2 mi.

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes, it is a good idea as you mentioned to set a default scale, this is something that I will implement. Right now I want to get y working because that is really the "unknown" at this point. So are you suggesting that I takes random samples of max and min then adjust my graph scale throughout the duration?

Comment: sometimes people just cover the range of the current graph.  So if somebody starts out on very flat ground, y could be only +-15 feet more or less.  The bad news is it jumps around a lot.  Otherwise you can just start with the idea that "everybody" will change in elevation by 100 feet and set that as a minimum scale, increasing it as required.  Really x and y work the same way in this regard.

Comment: Do you want to post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual approach is to choose some default scale for your graph and rescale if the data goes out of range. Maybe you start with 0-1mi on x and current altitude (rounded) +-200 ft on y. Then when somebody goes past 1 mi, change the horizontal (which requires updating all the points) to 0-2 mi

ometimes people just cover the range of the current graph. So if somebody starts out on very flat ground, y could be only +-15 feet more or less. The bad news is it jumps around a lot. Otherwise you can just start with the idea that "everybody" will change in elevation by 100 feet and set that as a minimum scale, increasing it as required. Really x and y work the same way in this regard. – Ross Millikan 1 hour ago

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving a sequence $(x_k,y_k)_{k\geq1}$ of data points in real time.
Initialize
$$a_1:=b_1:=x_1,\quad c_1:=d_1:=y_1$$
and update these boundaries by means of
$$\left.\eqalign{a_n&:=\min\{a_{n-1}, x_n\},\quad b_n:=\max\{b_{n-1}, x_n\},\cr
c_n&:=\min\{c_{n-1}, y_n\},\quad d_n:=\max\{d_{n-1}, y_n\}\cr}\right\}\qquad(n\geq2)\ .$$
Assuming $a_2\ne b_2$ and $c_2\ne d_2$ you can plot the $n\geq2$ data points received so far in the unit square $[0,1]^2$ as follows:
$$\eqalign{\xi_k:={x_k-a_n\over b_n-a_n} \cr \eta_k:={y_k-c_n\over d_n-c_n}\cr}\qquad (1\leq k\leq n)\ .$$

Comment: Christian, you lost me. I don't know math well enough to understand what you just posted.

Comment: @Nic Hubbard: It's just putting into formulas what Ross Millikan suggested. If you want to implement his advice you will have to use formulas of this kind.